# Sorting based on next and previous records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to order a specific query by taking the next and previous records into account, but I can't seem to get it done. I would like to order by a number and a letter, but if, for example, the last letter of number 1 is equal to one of the letters of number 2, I want to change the ordering, so that the letter matches with the following record.

<kbd>[`Create script and SQL fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff783/1)</kbd>

```
create table Parent (
id [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1), 
number bigint NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
GO

create table Child (
id [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1), 
parentId BIGINT, 
letter VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE (parentId, Letter),
FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES Parent(id)
)
GO

INSERT Parent (number) VALUES (1)
INSERT Parent (number) VALUES (2)
INSERT Parent (number) VALUES (3)

INSERT Child (parentId, letter) VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT Child (parentId, letter) VALUES (1, 'C')
INSERT Child (parentId, letter) VALUES (2, 'B')
INSERT Child (parentId, letter) VALUES (2, 'C')
INSERT Child (parentId, letter) VALUES (3, 'B')
INSERT Child (parentId, letter) VALUES (3, 'D')
```

**Current query**

Currently I am sorting with this query:

```
SELECT P.number, C.letter 
FROM Child C
JOIN Parent P ON C.parentId = P.id
ORDER BY P.number, C.letter
```

**Current result set**

```
number               letter
-------------------- ------
1                    A
1                    C
2                    B
2                    C
3                    B
3                    D
```

**Expected result set**

To clarify what I actually want to do, here is the expected result set (with C and B of number 2 switched).

```
number               letter
-------------------- ------
1                    A
1                    C
2                    C --switched
2                    B --switched
3                    B
3                    D
```

**Other requirements and question**

- It has to work in **SQL SERVER 2005**.
- There is a scenario where 3 letters per number are used, I am happy if it just uses the best match.
- *I am actually also interested in solutions for later versions of SQL Server (for learning), but those do not answer my question.*

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Please see this question for a new scenario that came to my mind, by the comments on the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480504/complex-sorting-based-on-next-and-previous-records-in-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this.

1. Identify first and last letter of each parent by using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY`
2. Match the last record of the preceding `id` with the first record of the next `id`.
3. Check if the second parent id has any letter which matches with the letter selected above
4. Use a `LEFT JOIN` and use `CASE` or `ISNULL` to set a higher priority for such an `id` record in which the letter had matched

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT id,ParentID,letter,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY parentId ORDER BY ID) first_element,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY parentId ORDER BY ID DESC) Last_element
FROM Child
), CTE2 AS 
(
SELECT c1.id,c1.parentid,c1.letter,c2.parentid as c2parentid
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2
ON c1.last_element = 1
AND c2.first_element = 1
AND c1.id +1 = c2.id
), CTE3 AS 
(
SELECT C.parentid,C.id
FROM CTE2
INNER JOIN child C ON CTE2.c2parentid = C.parentid
AND C.letter = CTE2.letter
)
SELECT P.number, C.letter
FROM Child C
JOIN Parent P ON C.parentId = P.id
LEFT JOIN CTE3 ON CTE3.id = C.id
ORDER BY P.number, ISNULL(CTE3.id,0) DESC, C.letter
```

**Output**

```
number  letter
1   A
1   C
2   C
2   B
3   B
3   D
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/242cc7/19)

**EDIT**

If your `ids` are not sequential, you can change `CTE1` and `CTE2` like this to utilize `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) seq_id`.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT id,ParentID,letter,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) seq_id,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY parentId ORDER BY ID) first_element,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY parentId ORDER BY ID DESC) Last_element
FROM Child
), CTE2 AS 
(
SELECT c1.id,c1.parentid,c1.letter,c2.parentid as c2parentid
FROM CTE c1
INNER JOIN CTE c2
ON c1.last_element = 1
AND c2.first_element = 1
AND c1.seq_id + 1 = c2.seq_id
)
```

Rest of the code remains same.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1438/2)

Comment: very nice, I was trying to do something like this but you were waaaaaaaaaay faster :p, I wasn't even halfway there

Comment: `AND c1.id +1 = c2.id` this concerns me a little, what if the ids are not succeeding?

Comment: you could do a `row_number() over(order by id)` and then use that

Comment: Here is your fiddle with another identity incrementation, can't seem to get it done with `row_number()` locally. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1438/1

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this looks very promising, going to try it now

Comment: Please try to swap the first two child element in the example. It seems that the output is wrong.

Comment: Well, if we swap the first two elements then there is no match as per OP's requirement. can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Nick said: "the last letter of number 1 is equal to one of the letters of number 2". ONE of the letters, and not the FIRST letter of number 2.

Comment: well if you swap the first two elements then `'A'` becomes the last letter for `1` which is not there in `2`, so nothing is swapped.

Comment: @GaborRajczi you actually have a point and I would like to know the answer to this question as well, since this is another scenario I need to figure out, should I create a new question for this? Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/676b74/1

Comment: @ughai the last letter in the number 1 is 'C'. It is independent from the child id. It is ordered by letter.

Comment: @GaborRajczi The answer to this question is perfect, I have created a new question with a more complex scenerio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480504/complex-sorting-based-on-next-and-previous-records-in-sql

Comment: @GaborRajczi - Ah I get you now, well if that is the case, then we need a `max(letter)` with `group by parent` number and then check if this letter is present in the subsequent parent. and I agree with Nick that this would constitute a different question :)

Comment: @GaborRajczi thanks for commenting, because the new question is actually what really interests me.